# Disemvowel in swift

Tags: swift

We can remove all of the vowels from the string in javascript just like this:

```
function disemvowel(str) {
  str = str.replace(/([aeiouAEIOU])/g, '')
  return str;
}
```

I implement it the same function in swift, just curious that how can write it shorter just as javascript?

```
func disemvowelTheString(string: String) -> String {
  var replacedString = string
  let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]

  for vowel in vowels {
    if string.containsString(vowel) {
      replacedString = replacedString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(vowel, withString: "")
    }
  }

  return replacedString
}
```

Comment: You could use the same regular expression. Also note that in javascript you can use `i` to make the comparison case insensitive therefore your regular expression will become just `/[aeiou]/gi`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to `filter` any vowels from the input string's characters:

```
func removeVowels(input: String) -> String {
    let vowels: [Character] = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
    let result = String(input.characters.filter { !vowels.contains($0) })
    return result
}
```

Comment: Did you see that I made `vowels` a `[Character]`? Either you convert the closure's argument to `String` or you compare it against an array of `Character`. Both should work.

Comment: Yep, missed that, was using the OP's original code :P

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using flatMap :

```
let string = "Hi how are you?"

let k = String(string.characters.flatMap(){

  if(!["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"].contains($0))
  {
    return $0
  }else{
    return nil
  }
})
```

Prints: H hw r y?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using the same regular expression:

```
func disemvowelTheString(string: String) -> String {
    return string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
        "[aeiou]",
        withString: "",
        options: [.RegularExpressionSearch, .CaseInsensitiveSearch]
    )
}
```

`.CaseInsensitiveSearch` takes care of `AEIOU`, the same way you could use `/[aeiou]/gi` in javascript.